# Split list of dictionaries with identical keys but different values to different dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Good day everyone.
I have a List of dictionaries with different games. The games are played in order. Each game can have a different number of keys.
There are several identical keys in dictionaries, but the meanings are different.
The problem is that I have not figured out how to separate games into different dictionaries using specific keys.

```
list = [{'SA': '1'}, {'ZA': 'AFRICA: African Nations Championship'}, {'ZEE': 'fZS33RAH'}, {'ZB': '1'}, {'ZY': 'Africa'}, {'ZC': 'AuZlotWi'}, {'ZD': 'p'}, {'ZE': 'hQF2OO7Q'}, {'ZF': '0'}, {'ZO': '0'}, {'ZG': '1'}, {'ZH': '1_fZS33RAH'}, {'ZJ': '2'}, {'ZL': '/football/africa/african-nations-championship/'}, {'ZX': '00Africa      006Africa0040000000001000African Nati028onship000'}, {'ZXF': '00Africa      006Africa0040000000001000African Nati028onship000'}, {'ZCC': '0'}, {'ZAF': 'Africa'}, {'AA': 'lv6E76jD'}, {'AD': '1611514800'}, {'ADE': '1611514800'}, {'AB': '3'}, {'CR': '3'}, {'AC': '3'}, {'CX': 'Burkina Faso'}, {'RW': '0'}, {'AX': '1'}, {'AO': '1611521595'}, {'BX': '-1'}, {'WQ': ''}, {'WM': 'BFA'}, {'AE': 'Burkina Faso'}, {'JA': 'vXsxyJv4'}, {'WU': 'burkina-faso'}, {'AS': '0'}, {'AZ': '0'}, {'GRA': '0'}, {'AG': '0'}, {'BA': '0'}, {'BC': '0'}, {'OA': '6FkKkDT0-d4SDTRYi.png'}, {'WN': 'CAM'}, {'AF': 'Cameroon'}, {'JB': 'INttzwfA'}, {'WV': 'cameroon'}, {'AS': '0'}, {'AZ': '0'}, {'GRB': '0'}, {'AH': '0'}, {'BB': '0'}, {'BD': '0'}, {'OB': '4MsJXS86-CMP7lutI.png'}, {'AA': 'jqpcWkTD'}, {'AD': '1611514800'}, {'ADE': '1611514800'}, {'AB': '3'}, {'CR': '3'}, {'AC': '3'}, {'CX': 'Zimbabwe'}, {'RW': '0'}, {'AX': '1'}, {'AO': '1611521438'}, {'BX': '-1'}, {'WQ': ''}, {'WM': 'ZIM'}, {'AE': 'Zimbabwe'}, {'JA': 'CptpZd9G'}, {'WU': 'zimbabwe'}, {'GRA': '0'}, {'AG': '0'}, {'BA': '0'}, {'BC': '0'}, {'OA': 'bBXMPUhT-QwFad6pm.png'}, {'WN': 'MAL'}, {'AF': 'Mali'}, {'JB': 'AVbmYGOM'}, {'WV': 'mali'}, {'AS': '2'}, {'AZ': '2'}, {'GRB': '0'}, {'AH': '1'}, {'BB': '1'}, {'BD': '0'}, {'OB': 'txCAqWjC-dWt4REwT.png'}, {'ZA': 'ALBANIA: Superliga'}, {'ZEE': 'nwPDBpVc'}, {'ZB': '17'}, {'ZY': 'Albania'}, {'ZC': 'ULkLo4dK'}, {'ZD': 'p'}, {'ZE': 'OKzcNHo0'}, {'ZF': '0'}, {'ZO': '0'}, {'ZG': '1'}, {'ZH': '17_nwPDBpVc'}, {'ZJ': '2'}, {'ZL': '/football/albania/superliga/'}, {'ZX': '00Albania     007lbania0000000000001000Superliga   009erliga000'}, {'ZXF': '00Albania     007lbania0000000000001000Superliga   009erliga000'}, {'ZCC': '0'}, {'ZAF': 'Albania'}]
```

Game keys is:

```
game_keys = ['AA', 'BA', 'BB', 'BC', 'BD', 'AB', 'AC', 'AG', 'AH', 'AT', 'AU', 'BI', 'BJ']
```

I tried to make a loop to check each element for the presence of a key, but it turns out to be complete nonsense:

```
match = []
for item in list:
    game_keys = ['AA', 'BA', 'BB', 'BC', 'BD', 'AB', 'AC', 'AG', 'AH', 'AT', 'AU', 'BI', 'BJ']
    if item.keys() == game_keys[0]:
        match_id = list(item.values())[0]
    elif item.keys() == game_keys[1]:
        home_HT = list(item.values())[0]
```

Is it possible to separate this list of dictionaries to different dictionaries (games) with "game_keys"?
Desired result:

```py
games = [
{
    'match_id': 'lv6E76jD' # game_keys 'AA', 
    'home_HT': '0' # game_keys 'BA', 
    'away_HT': '0' # game_keys 'BB', 
    'home_ST': '0' # game_keys 'BC'
},
# ...
# etc.
# ...
{
    'match_id': 'jqpcWkTD',
    'home_HT': '0',
    'away_HT': 0,
    'home_ST': 0
}
]
```

Comment: I think it's possible to reduce the code while keeping the reproducibility intact.

Comment: Don't call your list `list`. That will cause problems as you are redefining the keyword.

Comment: Can you make a much smaller example of data, whats your input, and expected output. Your data is to large to try to copy and replicate your issue and we dont really know what your output should look like

Comment: @ChrisDoyle  I'm trying to get the result look's like: Result:

{'match_id': 'lv6E76jD',
'home_HT': '0',
'away_HT': '0',
'home_ST': '0'}
...
...
{'match_id': 'jqpcWkTD',
'home_HT': '0',
'away_HT': 0,
'home_ST': 0}

Comment: Please make the example even smaller and add your expectations to your question as well. Thanks!

Comment: @Wolf  Done. Smaller list and expectations added

Comment: @alekvertysh I see, but it's still unclear how this result should be interpreted. It's no valid Python syntax. And reduction is still possible.

Comment: Your desired output seems devoid of any logic. Please elaborate the logic.

Comment: @alekvertysh Is *this* your expected result? see my reformatted question!

Comment: I'm tryin to make new list of dictionaries, every dictionary should contain values from list-data where keys match with keys from "game_keys"-list.

Comment: @Wolf  Yes! Thanks for the formatting. I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to collect valuable information from a large stream of input consisting of key-value pairs whereby the order in repeated "trains" of known keys is the same, here is my approach to this problem. I focus on the four keys presented as the expected result. I also use the last key `'BC'` as the trigger to complete an extracted dictionary. This special case is also the reason for hard-coding game_keys.

```py
games = [] # for collecting all results

match = {} # for collecting elements of single match (reused)
for item in input_list:
    key, value = list(item.items())[0]
    if 'AA' == key:
        match['match_id'] = value
    elif 'BA' == key:
        match['home_HT'] = value
    elif 'BB' == key:
        match['away_HT'] = value
    elif 'BC' == key:
        match['home_ST'] = value
        games.append(match)
        match = {} # reset for next match
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking if a value exist within a hashset or a dictionary is done with the keyword "in"
Converting the list game_keys in a hashset make more sense in your initial scenario, but most likely would need to be converted into a dictionary to map the desired result.

```
myListOfDictionaries = [{'SA': '1'}, {'AC': '3'}, {'BA': '0'}, {'AA': 'jqpcWkTD'}]
game_keys = set(['AA', 'BA', 'BB'])
match = {}
for myDictionary in myListOfDictionaries:
    for key in myDictionary:
        if(key in game_keys):
            if(key in match):
                match[key].append(myDictionary[key])
            else:
                match[key] = [myDictionary[key]]
```

To complete your task, I would assume you would need the game_keys to be a dictionary where the value would be "match_id" for the key "AA", "home_HT" for the key "BA"...

This would make it more flexible to create the desired result.

This isn't the final solution to your question, I do not believe you would learn much if I simply gave you the solution. I believe with this piece of code, you might be able to tackle creating a dictionary of dictionary.

In my sample, I have a dictionary "match", I lookup to see if the key exist, if it doesn't, I add a list of a single item into it... and if it exist, I know there a list of at least one item, so I append more item to it.

You can use the same logic to create a dictionary of dictionary.

Comment: I tried to make exceptions using a loop (with different options), but adding only the necessary keys to the new dictionary was my problem (I'm just starting to learn).
Thanks again.

Comment: This approach seems elegant in a way and is easier to maintain. On the other hand the performance of nested loops is of course not optimal. I know that this can be efficiently implemented in C, so imagine some module could provide specialized functions to transform `myListOfDictionaries` first.

Comment: @Wolf I must object that it's not performant... The code goes through the list once O(n), you might be stuck that it's a loop within a loop...

The list of myListOfDictionaries is a list of dictionary, so i go by every dictionary and every item of that said dictionary.

Performance issue is when we loop the same list or dictionary multiple time.